# Recursive expression of Lebesgue measure for balls with removed intersection

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, algorithms, lebesgue-measure

This is not the most theoretically challenging question; rather it is more of a reference request for a simple formula (which must be known).

---

Let $\left\{B_{\epsilon_n}(x_n)\right\}_{n=0}^N$ be a set of balls in $\mathbb{R}^d$ of radius $\epsilon_n>0$ and distinct centers $x_n\in \mathbb{R}^d$.  Define the sets
$$
B_0= B_{\epsilon_0}(x_0) \qquad B_{n+1}= B_{\epsilon_{n+1}}(x_{n+1}) - \bigcup_{k\leq n} B_n.
$$

1. What is an expression for the Lebesgue measure $\mu$ of $B_n$ of the form
   $$
   \mu\left(B_n\right) = F\left(x_n,\dots, x_1,\epsilon_n,\dots,\epsilon_1 \right)?
   $$
   for some function $F$?
2. Is there a *recursive* expression of the form
   $$
   G_1 = \mu(B_1)=Vol(B_1) \mbox{ and } 
   G_n = g\left(G_{n-1},x_n,\epsilon_n\right)
   $$
   for some reasonable function $g$?

---

So far the best I have found is [this](http://docsdrive.com/pdfs/ansinet/ajms/2011/66-70.pdf)...but that's not really an answer.

Comment: If I correctly understand the first question, the answer must be negative. There is no such $F$ because the available information, $x_n,\epsilon_n,\mu(B_{n-1})$ doesn't tell us anything about where $B_{n-1}$ is located relative to $x_n$.  For the second question, of course there exists a function $G$ satisfying the desired equation, but I see no reason for it to be simple

Comment: @AndreasBlass Right.  $F$ cannot exist.  However, there still may be a recursive formula for $G$...

Comment: @AndreasBlass, AIM_BLB, there seems to be some confusion in notation in your conversation. Indeed, there are no such recursive $g$ because of the reasons above: parameters don't remember how far is $В_n$ from previous balls. It may even not intersect them at all.

Comment: aha, but an $F$ definetly can exist... but is an expression known for it?  (This is my main question I guess)

Comment: @JosephGordon Note that my previous comment was about the original version of the question. Since then, the question has been edited with significant changes. You can see the original version (and the whole edit history) by clicking the "edited [n] hours ago" link at the end of the question.